# Problem in SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have very big problem in my SQL query and i don't know how to decide it.
So, i have query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE leftBorder <= 10 AND rightBorder >= 100
```

It's ok.

Next step.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE 
(leftBorder <= 10 AND rightBorder >= 100) OR (leftBorder <= 200 AND rightBorder >= 500)
```

It's ok.

But, i'd like to take values of left and right border from query, so:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE 
???
(SELECT leftBorder, rightBorder FROM table2 WHERE id in (1,2,3,4,5))
```

I need to make multi-condition for query in query... Is it possible? 
I don't have procedure, just query.

### I try to explain you:

```
SELECT TOP 1 leftBorder, rightBorder FROM table2 WHERE id in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

this return me 1 row with leftBorder and rightBorder and i can use it in query like:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE 
table1.leftBorder <= table2.leftBorder AND table1.rightBorder >= table2.rightBorder 
(SELECT TOP 1 leftBorder, rightBorder FROM table2 WHERE id in (1,2,3,4,5)) as table2
```

BUT! It works just when i have 1 row return from query. But what should i do, if i have 10 rows in return and i have to generate query for 10 conditions? Could i do it in query?

Comment: It's not really clear what you want here...

Comment: You have to understand that you certainly know what you want to accomplish but all the rest of us have is two tables of unknown purpose and structure that must be joined following a vague description of a rule...

Comment: Are you looking for rows from table1 where the `leftBorder` and `rightBorder` values are the same as the values for the records with the `id` values you specify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `EXISTS` condition :

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM table1 
  WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT * 
        FROM table2 
        WHERE table2.leftBorder>=table1.leftBorder 
        and table2.rightBorder<=table1.rightBorder)
```

Comment: See the [documentation of EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can select your values in a  subquery and there are several options for you, either you can:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE l leftBorder <= (SELECT leftBorder FROM table2 WHERE id IN(1,2,3,4,5)
```

or you could select from table in subquery and use alias like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1,  
    (SELECT leftBorder FROM table2 WHERE id IN(1,2,3,4,5) as temp 
WHERE leftBorder<= temp.leftBorder
```

Depends on what you want to achieve exactly and capabilities of your DBS

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, I guess what you need is something like this:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT t1.*
FROM
    table1 t1
JOIN
    table2 t2 
    ON (
        t1.leftBorder <= t2.leftBorder
        AND t1.rightBorder >= t2.rightBorder
        AND t2.id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
    )
```